# I failed to load data in same window second screen Electron js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, render

After successfully logging in, from first screen I am requesting some data from web & I want that data set to transfer to the next screen but my application failed to load that data set onto the screen.

From html file I require **renderer.js** like below

```
<script>
   require('./renderer.js');
</script>
```

After a successful login, I called the following event in **main.js** from **renderer.js**

```
if ($("#proceed").length > 0) {

  $("#proceed").on('click', function () {
    var data = '';
    ipcRenderer.send('producer-proceed', data);
  })
}
```

This following code is in **main.js**

```
ipcMain.on('producer-proceed',function (event,arg) {

    var user_name_data = 'Lorem Data';
    mainWindow.webContents.send('set_data', user_name_data);
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'screen.html'));

});
```

To load data onto the html I called the following event in **renderer.js**

```
ipcRenderer.on('set_data', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#seuser_name").text(data);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a `webContents.send` once the window is [ready-to-show](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#using-ready-to-show-event)?

Comment: No. Isn't create the problem? Cause I fired an event from renderer to get some data on main.js file if success then it will redirect to service.html url.

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but to me, the flow seems a bit off because you're loading the URL for your screen _after_ you send the `webContents`. I would expect that to be the other way around.